# question remains closed even after update edit

Tags: support

I had asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683953/where-is-apache-web-root-directory-on-ubuntu) some time back and it got closed as I did not respond to the notice to modify it. I later did and up till now the question has not received any attention.

I don't know if my update edit was accepted or not, and if not I can re-edit to re-open the question.

Is there a special means to request a re-open?

Comment: Still a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2/, IMO

Comment: ok @muru i get this as its a better reason but the `reason` for the close says `unclear` that is what I don't get. Thanks I feel better

Comment: it does take 5 people to reopen and another 5 to close again, so if I reviewed that, I'd probably leave it closed just because of the waste of effort involved in reopening just to close again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your update edit was indeed accepted (it's your question, so you always have the right to edit it). However, as Muru pointed out, your question is still a duplicate, so I reopened it and closed as a dupe of [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2/).

If that doesn't answer your question, edit it (yes, again :) to clarify what more you need.

Comment: It was answered, just wondered why it was closed with that reason. Muru did a great job explaining it to and I'm okay with that.